# gradle multiproject fails when implement another subproject

Tags: scala, kotlin, gradle

I am recently learning gradle and I tried to build multi project module.
The project structure is like

```bash
.
├─ build.gradle.kts
├─ settings.gradle.kts
├─ sub1
│  └── build.gradle.kts
│  └── src
├─ sub2
│  └── build.gradle.kts
│  └── src
```

`sub1` is first subproject and `sub2` is second subproject.

`sub1` project is built in **kotlin** with **spring-starter-jpa**

`sub2` project is build in **scala** with **spark**

What I need now is implement `sub1` project from `sub2` and use a Map. All the logic `sub1` has is to create that Map, so other sub projects can implement and use it. In above example there is no `sub3` but in my real project there is several other sub projects which are built in kotlin and use `spring-starter-jpa` as well. At those sub projects implement `sub1` works fine but it only fails to build with `sub2`. Followings are `gradle.build.kts` for each project.

`build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("gradle.plugin.org.datlowe.maven-publish-auth:buildSrc:2.0.2")
        classpath("com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.1.0")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${project.properties["kotlinVersion"]}")
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "osgeo-release"
            url = uri("https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release")
        }
        maven {
            name = "hortonworks"
            url = uri("https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases")
        }

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    configurations {
        all {
            exclude(module = "spring-boot-starter-logging")
        }
    }

    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")

    group = "example"
    version = "0"
}

subprojects {
    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }

    tasks.withType<Test> {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

`sub1/build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring") //version is handled at setting.gradle.kts not important
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") 
    id("org.springframework.boot")
    id("io.spring.dependency-management")
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint")
}

dependencies {
    // kotlin
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")

    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

    implementation("javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api")

    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
}
```

`sub2/build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow")
    id("application")
    id("scala")
    id("com.github.maiflai.scalatest")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":sub1"))

    implementation("org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.11")

    testImplementation("org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:3.2.3")
    testImplementation("org.scalatestplus:junit-4-13_2.12:3.2.3.0")

    testRuntimeOnly("com.vladsch.flexmark:flexmark-all:0.35.10")
}

application {
    mainClass.set("my.application.path")
}

tasks.withType<ScalaCompile>().configureEach {
    scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = listOf("-feature")
}

tasks.withType<JavaCompile>().configureEach {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
```

When I build `sub2` it thorws

```
Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:.
Required by:
    project :sub1
```

Can you guys please help me?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but if I add all the implementation and plugin and repository related to `sub1` at `sub2` does solve this problem.